# Error when trying to perform postgres queries (triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I was trying to perform postgres queries using node but for some reason is not fetching the data from postgres.

See my database.js below:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const client = new Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: PORT,
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'postgres',
    database: 'ecommerce'
})

client.connect();

client.query('select * from customers', (err, result) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(result.rows)
    } else {
        console.log(err)
    }
    client.end();
})
```

Please note that the customers table is a valid table in my ecommerce database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask], would you be kind enough to post the full error?

Comment: Hey ! sure , see below the error : connection error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16)

Answer (score 1):

You should wait the client to connect.

See the docs [here](https://node-postgres.com/api/client)

```
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client()
client
  .connect()
  .then(() => console.log('connected'))
  .catch(err => console.error('connection error', err.stack))
```

Instead of `console.log('connected')`,  write your query.

Comment: thanks ! the error changed to : connection error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16)

Comment: Probably because pg server usually run on port 5432, not 3000